# To find the line number of the string searched in Python

Tags: python, string, search

```
    def c1():
        logfile = open("D:\myfile.txt", 'r')
        for num1, line in enumerate(logfile):
                if "request=100" in line:
                    print num1
                    return True
        return False

    def c2():
        logfile = open("D:\myfile.txt", 'r')
        for num2, line in enumerate(logfile):
                if "response=200" in line:
                    print num2
                    return True
        return False    

    if c1() == True and c2() == True:
        print "Test Case Passed"  
    else:
        print "Test Case Failed"
```

In the above code, checking for the line number so that request=100 and response=200 will fall in same line is not present. That I need.

Also, I want to print the result as "Pass" only if the following conditions are met ...

```
- both c1 and c2 are True
- both "request=100" and "response=200" should fall in same line 
- if any other line also consist of "request=100" and "response=200" then that also should be counted
```

Result is "Fail" if :

```
- if any one line which consists of "request=200" and "response=200"
- if any one line which consists of "request=100" and "response=100" 
- or any case in which no line should have apart from "request=100" and "response=200"
```

Consider "myfile" is having the following data :

```
request=100 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \n
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX response=200 XXXXXXXXX \n
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \n
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \n
XXXX request=100 XXXXX response=200 XXXXXXXXXXX \n
XXXXXXX request=200 XXXXXX response=100 XXXXXXX \n
XXXXXXXX request=100 XXXX response=100"         \n
```

In the above file, result is Fail because request and response have different values apart from the required values. Only line 5 has correct values, hence the result is failed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should put both conditions in one loop, and keep looping until you hit the end of the line, or encounter another line with the condition:

```
def are_they_on_the_same_line():
    logfile = open("D:\myfile.txt", 'r')
    intermediate_result = False
    for num1, line in enumerate(logfile):
            if "request=100" in line and "response=200":
                if intermediate_result == True:
                    return False
                intermediate_result = True
    return intermediate_result
```

There are other conditions in which this fails, except for the fail-conditions you've mentioned. But the two you mention are not mutually exclusive.

Edit: No wait this is wrong, judging from the example. I cannot make sense of your conditions. Maybe it helps you to get an idea, if not, please clarify the conditions with another example.